# Fiddler parallel http request limitation

Tags: http, https, httprequest, fiddler

I am using **Fiddler** to test my computer's http request performance, and
I want to send 200 parallel request exactly at same time (within variance 20ms).

My computer has 8 Core CPU.
And I found that I only can send 8x10 =80 requests at **same time** in maximum.

An example while sending 85 requests: https://upload.cc/i1/2021/03/17/VbUSmf.jpg

I'm quite sure that it's all about the limitation of Fiddler or the number of CPU core.
As my friend's computer has 10 core, and he can send 10x10 =100 requests exactly at same time.

How can I increase the maximum number of parallel request at **same time**?
~Greatly Appreciate for any help~

Comment: How do you create the requests (program/language/http client)? Often clients also have limitations regarding maximum parallel HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just use the software "Fiddler Classic" to send http request to the testing host:https://example.com.
Actually I have tried other host and also get the same result. 
If I send more than 80 request, there will be high latency.